# Как задать имя отправителя для почтового клиента?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вот как приходит письмо. В самом начале имя "WordPress".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код php. Делается на WordPress

```
<?php
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
    wp_mail('mymail@gmail.com','Brilgo', 'Спасибо вам за вашу заявку. Мы скоро свяжемся с вами', $headers);
?>
```

Как поменять имя "WordPress" на "Brilgo"? Не очень когда на почту клиента приходит имя "WordPress" .

Comment: Нужно изучать используемые функции https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_mail. Прямо в самом начале написано. А так же нужно знать [почтовые заголовки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B0#%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Answer (score 0):

Добавил эти строки после headers[]

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function( $content_type ){
    return "text/html";
} );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'vortal_wp_mail_from_name' );
function vortal_wp_mail_from_name( $email_from ){
    return 'Brilgo';
}
```